# How to skip tab order from expansion panel?

Tags: angular, mat-expansion-panel

I have input fields inside mat-expansion-panel.
When pressing tab key, the tab orders include mat-expansion-panel.
so I set tabindex=-1 in  but still does not skip mat-expansion-panel when pressing tab key.

When pressing tab key, cursor moves as below

[image]

But I want to skip Peronal data expansion panel and I want cursor to move as below

[image]

tabindex=-1 does not work. How can I achieve this? Here is [stackbiz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qtpefa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fexpansion-steps-example.html)

Comment: Have you tried disabled input on mat-exapansion panel?

Answer (score 0):

Set a templateRef and access it with ViewChild in component

html

```
<mat-expansion-panel-header #panelHeader>
```

ts

```
@ViewChild('panelHeader', { read: ElementRef }) panelHeader: ElementRef;
```

Then in the AfterViewInit hook (remember to implement it in your class), set the `tabIndex` of the `panelHeader` as follows

```
@Component({
  selector: 'expansion-steps-example',
  templateUrl: 'expansion-steps-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['expansion-steps-example.css'],
})
export class ExpansionStepsExample implements AfterViewInit{
  @ViewChild('panelHeader', { read: ElementRef }) panelHeader: ElementRef;
  step = 0;

  setStep(index: number) {
    this.step = index;
  }

  nextStep() {
    this.step++;
  }

  prevStep() {
    this.step--;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.panelHeader.nativeElement.tabIndex = -1;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `tabindex="1"` on all your inputs. If you don't want to clutter your templates, you can use a directive that does that automatically:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: 'input',
})
export class TabIndexOne {
  @HostBinding('tabindex') idx = 1;
}
```

Example [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qtpefa-ymtvgd?file=src/app/tab-index-one.directive.ts)